# babel disable quotation mark translation

Tags: babel, unicode, german

I am using the babel ngerman package and my inputenc is set to utf-8, so I only need the translation strings for things like the `\tableofcontents`. How can I disable the Umlaut translation like `"overflow"` -> överflow", without having to escape the quotation mark?

Comment: \shorthandoff{"}

Comment: You shouldn't be using `"` anyway.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use the `csquotes` package for such stuff

Comment: Or at least use `\`\`overflow''`. (But `csquotes` is better.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer's suggestion also fixes `! Argument of \language@active@arg has an extra }.` errors for e.g. Dutch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a command `\afz{Overflow}` which provides german style of "" - quotes.

(afz stands for "Anführungszeichen", the German word for this ;-))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[babel,style=german]{csquotes}

\newcommand{\afz}[1]{\enquote{#1}}%



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\section{\afz{Overflow}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay, I will start using csquotes from now :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MoritzHoffmann: `csquotes` ist der einfachste Weg, um deutsche Anführungszeichen zu erhalten.

Comment: Why the additional command to wrap around enquote?